# Why can I pull out the maximum of an integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

I have the following problem.

> We have $R\subset \Bbb{C}$ a rectangle and $\{f_n\}$ a collection of analytic functions which converges uniformly to $f$. After a long computation we got to the following point $$\int_{\partial R} |f(z)-f_n(z)|dz$$ Then our prof wrote the following inequality:$$\int_{\partial R} |f(z)-f_n(z)|dz\leq max_{z\in \partial R}|f_n(z)-f(z)|\cdot\int_{\partial R} |dz|$$

And I somehow don't see why one can take the maximum outside and leave the rest.

Could maybe someone explain this to me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It might be easier to think about this kind of *bound* for a summation instead of for the integral.

Comment: @hardmath so I mean If I have a sum of maybe $n$ summands then I have that it is smaller that $n$ times the max. But does this mean that I can think about the remaining integral as about $n$?

Comment: Yes, and you can make the idea rigorous by taking the integral as a limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: ah wow perfect thanks!